# ethereum-php library SmartContract balanceOf always returns 0

Tags: ether, erc-20, parity, php

I am trying to check balance of some USDT token using ethereum-php library but it always return 0.

Here is the code,

```
    $contractMeta = json_decode('[{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_upgradedAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"deprecate","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"deprecated","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_evilUser","type":"address"}],"name":"addBlackList","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"upgradedAddress","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balances","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"maximumFee","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"_totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"unpause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_maker","type":"address"}],"name":"getBlackListStatus","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"paused","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"who","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"pause","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getOwner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newBasisPoints","type":"uint256"},{"name":"newMaxFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setParams","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"issue","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"redeem","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"name":"_spender","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"remaining","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"basisPointsRate","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"isBlackListed","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_clearedUser","type":"address"}],"name":"removeBlackList","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"MAX_UINT","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_blackListedUser","type":"address"}],"name":"destroyBlackFunds","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_initialSupply","type":"uint256"},{"name":"_name","type":"string"},{"name":"_symbol","type":"string"},{"name":"_decimals","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Issue","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Redeem","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"newAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"Deprecate","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"feeBasisPoints","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"maxFee","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Params","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_blackListedUser","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_balance","type":"uint256"}],"name":"DestroyedBlackFunds","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"AddedBlackList","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"_user","type":"address"}],"name":"RemovedBlackList","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Pause","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[],"name":"Unpause","type":"event"}]');
    $contract = new SmartContract(
        $contractMeta,
        "0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7", // USDT contract address
        $eth
    );

    $x = $contract->balanceOf(new \Ethereum\DataType\EthD20("0x2258a37ac1e154c8aa34e91c29d511c7ed5d4f13"));
    var_dump($x->val()); // returns int(0)
```

Can somebody check what I am doing wrong here?

I copied this code from the official documentation.
https://github.com/digitaldonkey/ethereum-php

Comment: I don't know PHP, but try to remove the `new \Ethereum\DataType\EthD20` part. Function `balanceOf` takes a simple Ethereum address. Of course, you still need to pass it as a string (not sure about PHP, that's the case in JS).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's not the case, library requires the parameter passed as ETHD object. Tried without that, gives a fatal error.

Comment: Which node are you using? Is it completely synchronized?

Comment: The problem is not with the node as its completely synced. The problem is in the library, I tried the same with web3-php library and it worked but not working with ethereum-php. And for the record, node is Parity/OpenEthereum.